# Set inputType for an EditText within an Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I am trying to add a AlertDialog to ask for people's name when they 1st start an app. I have created an EditText for entry purpose. I want to change the input type for this EditText to ensure capitalization at word level as I am expecting proper names. I referred to multiple links, they all provided the same answer,

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Hello!");
    alert.setMessage("What is your name?");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this)
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS)
    alert.setview(input)
```

But it is not working. Throwing me an error saying "cannot resolve symbol 'InputType'". Please help.

I am new to Android apps. If there is more information you require, please let me know. I could not figure out what exactly will be required. Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this import to your source file:

```
import android.text.InputType;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm wondering why your IDE didn't give you more help finding the missing import.  In Android Studio, you can click on the type that needs the import, and then Alt-Enter to have the import automatically added.  As a last result, you can google the missing type, e.g. "android Input Type".  Usually the first hit is to the documentation page.  Near the top, in small font, is the package containing the type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried with Alt-Enter. But it did not work. That is why I was confused if the problem was with import or some other. Android Studio working fine for other android object types.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
  final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);  
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  input.setLayoutParams(lp);
  input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS)
  alertDialog.setView(input);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I would definitely try it out sometime. But the correct answer I was looking for is below. I thought it was a import problem. But could not figure out the one required.